# A question about the minimizer of a convex question

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I am stuck with the following question about convex functions:

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is an L-smooth convex function, and $\textbf{x}^*$ is a minimizer of $f(\textbf{x})$. Assume that $\|\textbf{x}^*-\textbf{x}_0\|_2\leq R$ for some finite $R>0$. For a very small $\epsilon>0$, denote $f_\epsilon(\textbf{x})=f(x)+\frac{\epsilon}{2R^2}\|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0\|_2^2$, and $\textbf{x}_\epsilon^*$ as a minimizer of $f_\epsilon(\textbf{x})$.

Given these conditions, can I say that $\|\textbf{x}_\epsilon^*-\textbf{x}_0\|_2$ is bounded by $C\|\textbf{x}^*-\textbf{x}_0\|_2$, where C is a positive constant? If yes, then how to prove it? If not, then how to relate the upper bound of it with respect to a function of $\|\textbf{x}^*-\textbf{x}_0\|$ of a function of R?

Comment: What does this mean: “Assume that $\|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0\|_2\leq R$ for some finite $R>0$.” What is $x_0$ and what is $x$ for that sentence? Do you really mean to assume $x_0$ is a particular point that is within a distance $R$ from $x^*$?

Comment: Sorry for my typo. Corrected version is posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $\delta>0$. Regardless of the structure of the function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (convex/non-convex),  if $x^*$ is a minimizer of $f$ and if  $x_{\delta}^*$ minimizes $f(x) + \delta ||x-x_0||^2$,  then by definition of minimizer:
\begin{align}
f(x_{\delta}^*) + \delta ||x_{\delta}^*-x_0||^2 &\leq f(x^*) + \delta ||x^*-x_0||^2 \\
&\leq f(x_{\delta}^*) + \delta ||x^*-x_0||^2 \\
\end{align}
where the final inequality holds because $f(x^*)\leq f(x_{\delta}^*)$ by definition of $x^*$ as a minimizer of $f$. Thus
$$ ||x_{\delta}^*-x_0||^2 \leq ||x^*-x_0||^2$$
$$ \implies \boxed{||x_{\delta}^*-x_0|| \leq ||x^*-x_0||}$$
You can choose $\delta = \epsilon/(2R^2)$ if you like.

---

You can get a better bound by using the fact that $f$ is convex (not necessarily differentiable) and using the
"strongly convex pushback" lemma, for example in Lemma 6 on page 23 here:

http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/convexity-chapter-fast-convex-programming.pdf

If $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is convex then $f(x) + \delta||x-x_0||^2$ is strongly convex, and if $x^*_{\delta}$ minimizes $f(x) + \delta||x-x_0||^2$ then by the strongly convex pushback lemma:
$$ f(x^*_{\delta}) + \delta ||x_{\delta}^*-x_0||^2 \leq f(x) + \delta||x-x_0||^2 - \underbrace{\delta||x-x^*_{\delta}||^2}_{pushback} \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d$$
Substituting $x^*$ in replace of $x$ in the above inequality gives
\begin{align}
f(x^*_{\delta}) + \delta ||x_{\delta}^*-x_0||^2 &\leq f(x^*) + \delta||x^*-x_0||^2 - \delta||x^*-x^*_{\delta}||^2\\
&\leq f(x^*_{\delta}) + \delta||x^*-x_0||^2 - \delta||x^*-x^*_{\delta}||^2
\end{align}
It follows that
$$ ||x_{\delta}^*-x_0||^2 \leq ||x^*-x_0||^2 -||x^*-x^*_{\delta}||^2 $$